# Replace infinite values with max/min value of a row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example data frame that looks like this:

```
x <- data.frame(val1 = c(1,4,5,2), val2 = c(4,2,46,2), val3 = c(Inf, 1, 4, 9), val4 = c(13, 51, 3, -Inf))
> x
    val1 val2 val3 val4
1    1    4  Inf   13
2    4    2    1   51
3    5   46    4    3
4    2    2    9 -Inf
```

I'd like to replace the infinite values with the maximum value of each row. Similarly I'd like to replace the negative infinite values with the minimum value of each row. The final data frame would look as follows:

```
val1 val2 val3 val4
1    1    4   13   13
2    4    2    1   51
3    5   46    4    3
4    2    2    9    2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `raster::clamp`

```r
as.data.frame(t(apply(x, 1, function(i) {
  raster::clamp(i, min(i[is.finite(i)]), max(i[is.finite(i)]))
})))

#>   val1 val2 val3 val4
#> 1    1    4   13   13
#> 2    4    2    1   51
#> 3    5   46    4    3
#> 4    2    2    9    2
```

Comment: this seems not giving the desired output ...

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding you're right - I was going column-wise instead of row-wise

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick solution with [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/), which will appropriately [`mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) each [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) a value [`is.infinite()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/is.finite.html), [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) [`everything()`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/everything.html) in your dataset:

## Solution

```
library(dplyr)


# ...
# Code to generate data frame 'x'.
# ...


x %>%
  mutate(across(
    # For every column you want...
    everything(),

    # ...change its values where appropriate:
    ~ case_when(
      # +Inf becomes the finite max.
      . ==  Inf ~ max(.[is.finite(.)]),
      # -Inf becomes the finite min.
      . == -Inf ~ min(.[is.finite(.)]),
      # Other values stay the same.
      TRUE      ~ .
    )
  ))
```

## Results

Given a dataset `x` like the one reproduced here

```
x <- data.frame(
  val1 = c(1, 4, 5, 2),
  val2 = c(4, 2, 46, 2),
  val3 = c(Inf, 1, 4, 9),
  val4 = c(13, 51, 3, -Inf)
)
```

this solution should yield the following result:

```
  val1 val2 val3 val4
1    1    4    9   13
2    4    2    1   51
3    5   46    4    3
4    2    2    9    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the `range` for each row with the finite values and do the assignment with `min/max` based on the infinite value and the `sign`

```
x[] <- t( apply(x, 1, function(x) {
     x1 <- range(x[!is.infinite(x)])
     x[is.infinite(x) & sign(x) < 0] <- x1[1]
     x[is.infinite(x)] <- x1[2]
   x}))
```

-output

```
> x
  val1 val2 val3 val4
1    1    4   13   13
2    4    2    1   51
3    5   46    4    3
4    2    2    9    2
```